# How to print text below and above Passed: in the console area in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-dataprovider

I have three @test methods to add, update and delete records in a webpage, once my execution completes I am looking for an output something like below, where can I use the sisout to print the highlighted messages, I am running my code in TestNG.

[image]

```
   @Test(priority=2)
  void updateAddressBook() {
try{
driver.findElement(By.id("radio1")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("edit")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("company")).clear();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("company")).sendKeys("Vuram");
driver.findElement(By.id("add")).click();
Log.info("Validate company name is updated for user 2");
Reporter.log("Company name sucessfully updated for user 2");
passCount++;
}  catch (Error e) {
    verificationErrors.append("Cannot provide the input please stick to the UI constraints5.\n");
} catch(Exception e){
    verificationErrors.append("Cannot provide the input please stick to the UI constraints6.\n");
}

try {
    String x = driver.findElement(By.id("result")).getText();
    if(x.contains("Vuram"));
    {  
        passCount++;
    }
 } catch (Error e) {
    verificationErrors.append("Element by id 'td' not found.\n");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    verificationErrors.append("Element by id 'td' not found.\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using TestNG listeners?

Comment: Share your Trial Code.

Comment: Hi thanks, I used ITestListener and IReporter with the below line, @Listeners({WebPage.ListenerTest.class,WebPage.CustomReporter.class} )

Comment: hi @IshitaShah, pasted one of  the methods in the description area, I have used listerners on top of it, but this listeners, I am not sure whether I need to modify the listeners @Listeners({WebPage.ListenerTest.class,WebPage.CustomReporter.class} )

Comment: @Jagadeesh you don't need any listeners. Refer my solution as sample demo.

Comment: @IshitaShah, that's exactly what I want, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution what are you looking for, Just implement it sample demo:

**System.out.println(); for Console Logs**

**@Test(description = "") for Test Description**

```
public class demo {

    @Test(description = "This is description of Test Case")
    public void TestDemo() {

        System.out.println("****************************");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("****************************");
    }

}
```

[image: Console]